# Jupyter nbextension toc2 : the toolbar is covered, it can not show "contents"

Tags: jupyter, tableofcontents, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I am trying to use the toc2, but when I enable this, I cannot see all the contents in my Jupyter like the picture shown below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pChI.png)
I am using Safari to run Jupyter and here is my version of nbextension.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcDVl.png)

I have tried to change the version of nbextension and go to the "edit notebook metadata" change the setting following by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198589/some-setting-changes-in-table-of-contents-2-toc2-in-nbextensions-not-showing-u).

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrade to 6.4.12 using code below. Then drag the TOC from sidebar to make if floating and then drag it back to sidebar. It should place the TOC in your chosen height.

```
pip install notebook==6.4.12
```